# How can I skip the top hierarchy of json file and recreate it as a new json file?

Tags: python, arrays, json, hierarchy

I created an API call to download a json file which looks like this:

{
    "_v": "19.10",
    "_type": "store_result",
    "count": 30,
    "data": [
        {
            "_type": "store",
            "address1": "46 Fre...",
            ....., 
        },
        {
        "_type": "store",
            "address1": "915 ....',
            .....,
         },
         {
            .....,
            .....,
         }]

I want to add this data to a table but having trouble loading this data with the top hierarchy. How can I recreate this file with just the json objects in "data":[] while skipping the top 3 lines ("_v": "19.10", "_type": "store_result", "count": 30,)?

Comment: `json_results['data']` will be just the items you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on no example code the following code might suit you.

```
import requests
data = requests.get(yourURL).json()

results = data['data']
for result in results:
    # Iterates over the json objects in the data array
    # Can log this to a file if you wanted to
    print(result)
```